# navigator.mimeTypes consistency

Tags: javascript, browser

I'm thinking of using the browser's navigator.mimeTypes array as a means of a tertiary user/browser identifier.  So, for example, on my Chrome when I run...

```
console.log(navigator.mimeTypes[4].type);
```

I get "application/vnd.chromium.remoting-viewer"

I totally get that more than one person could have their mimeType set as something identical to mine.  I also totally get that anything client-side like this could be thwarted by an attacker relatively easily.

What I want to know is, what degree of consistency could I expect one person's browser's mimeTypes to stay the same?

If maybe 1 out of 100 or more could end up changing over the course of a year that would be fine.  But 1 out of 20 ends up changing that's going to be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to do browser fingerprinting, which has been researched an awful lot of before. [Here's a good primer to start with](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/122372/91371).

Specifically, visit [Panopticlick](https://panopticlick.eff.org/) to discover the uniqueness of your own browser based on shared information. The array you use is shown in their *"Browser Plugin Details"* output and provides quite some precision apparently.